# DNS lookup for Service Container on Internal Docker network does not work on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a Service Docker Container that works fine on my windows machine but when I try to run the same on my Linux machine I get the issue that the service can't find the injected service.

**Details:**

1. Service A container created using docker compose file.
2. Service B Container injected using the Environment variable into service A container
3. Service A container works fine and also Service B container works fine.
4. Issue comes when Service A container tries to access service B container. The Service B container is not reachable. The internal DNS for Service B could not be resolved by Service A container.
5. Service A and Service B container are connected to a Internal network manually created as a part of Docker compose file. The DNS for Service B gets resolved easily when I run these Linux containers on Windows Host OS but the same thing fails when I run it in Linux Host OS.

I have tried several things and have come to the conclusion that the 
- Internal DNS of Service B could be resolved by Service A in Windows Host OS but could not be resolved in Linux OS.

**DockerCompose (Part of the main file)**

```
services:
  serviceb:
    container_name: serviceb
    image: serviceb
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - "30041:80"
    networks: 
     - internal-network
  servicea:
    container_name: servicea
    image: servicea
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - "30091:80"
    networks: 
     - internal-network
    environment: 
      ConnectionString__Service: http://serviceb:80
    depends_on: 
      -serviceb
networks: 
  internal-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: test
```

Note: ServiceA and ServiceB is for reference purpose

I have written logs in my service and can check that the DNS is getting resolved in Windows case but not in Linux case.
Why Linux is behaving different is the major concern.

**Log for Linux machine :**
Below is the response i get when I access Service B.
[image]

The only difference I see in my windows and Linux Environment is that Windows Environment has no proxy while the Linux Environment has Proxy on its network.

Edit 1:
**I have searched a lot and now able to figure out that the  issue comes only on a Proxy network. I could confirm this because the setup is working fine on a machine without a proxy network.**  I have set the proxy in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf file and it is carried inside the Docker Container.

Comment: What do you mean by "access Service B"? Is there any chance you could share a fully reproducable example orf your problem?

Comment: I mean to say when Service A tries to access an API endpoint exposed by service B. The Service A creates an HTTP client for service B and then accesses the API of service B. The client application accesses the Service A endpoint and gets the response.

Comment: That `docker-compose.yml` file looks reasonable.  Can you show a relevant fragment of the application code that's actually making the network call; is it correctly finding the environment variable?  You show an image that's the response from the remote service; usually services don't return images on error, are there actual log messages that you can include (as text) in the question?

Comment: I am sure that the environment variable are read correctly because if I change the DNS to IP service B could be accessed. The screen shot I have added is the Snapshot of the log file that writes the response.I have created a normal HTTP client and there is nothing else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue surely was beacuse of the Proxy existing in the network. I have modified the `~/.docker/config.json` with the Proxy values and then created the containers. The proxy values were also set inside the containers and when I tried to make the service discovery the DNS failed.

Problem: The HTTP client that was created to access the service B from Service A was using the Proxy values. The proxy values inside the container were preventing the service discovery.

Solution:

1. Don't set Proxy values inside the container ie don't modify config.json OR
2. Create a Http Client with `useProxy=false`